# Jersey - data validation before sending entity object to REST api

Tags: validation, rest, jersey, marshalling

I use Jersey framework to communicate (marshalling and unmarshalling object and xml) with REST api. I send data (object has lot attributes) this way:

```
.
.   
ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/xml").post(ClientResponse.class, object);
.
```

I would like to ask how can I validate some object attributes (for example private String code in Object should be in format of two numbers etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aYou mean in the service that receives the object? How have you tried? It comes in as an object, or whatever you want it to come in as. We frequently take in `Map<String,Object>` and then do validation on that map (if we need to decide what subtype to create from the post for example). If you have Jersey unmarshall your request into the POJO for you, you can then do whatever validation you want and return a Response object with the validation error information to your client if the object doesn't pass.

So in other words, the validation is up to you. There are a few validation frameworks out there that you could try to help, such as javax.validation but IMHO it's usually easier to just test each property you need to validate yourself using conditionals, regexps, whatever.

Comment: I mean in my client side. I dont have acces to the service (and its source code) that receives the object. The server side gave me some .xsd from which I have some model classes generated. Now I am filling this classes (for example I have class called Admission and this class has attribute "private String code;" ...and I set some code, f.e. 1234a5 in my application but that value should be only digital so this form is wrong and the correct is 12345) with some data I would like to have some validator or something like that which doesn't send invalid object to the server API.

Comment: Is the data valid based on the xsd?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the validation comes with a webframework like struts, wicked, jfc... to name some. There the user inputs his data in a form to create the object he wants to post to a service. The webframeworks already got components to validate this data. When there was a positive validation you make the post call to your service.